# How to compare audio channel differences with FFmpeg?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg

I'm making a little script for myself to quickly go through a large volume of video and audio files to compress audio for extra space, but for extra efficiency, I also don't want to waste space by keeping both channels if they're identical.

My issue is that I don't know how to, let's say, check if their decoded versions are at least a 99.99% match, in which case I'd only encode the left channel into mono.

If necessary, I'm (was) somewhat proficient at Python, though it was quite a while ago since I have last done any programming. So, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use the [streamhash muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#streamhash-1) if you want to check if both channels are an **exact**, 100% match:

```
ffmpeg -v error -i stereo.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c0[left];[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c1[right]" -map "[left]" -map "[right]" -f streamhash -hash md5 -
0,a,MD5=11b849313c9e5e99b91e30a65eca8cca
1,a,MD5=11b849313c9e5e99b91e30a65eca8cca
```

This is assuming all of your inputs are stereo.

Comment: Can they be identical if, let's say, a mono device was recorded as stereo and then compressed to 320kbps as AAC after further post-processing?

Comment: @Deivedux Not necessarily. Depends on the encoder, encoding options, and post-processing.